# Prove: $\{∃xp(x), ∃xp(x) → \forall x∃y[p(x)→q(y)]\} ⊢ \forall xq(x) ∨ ∃xr(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I don’t think I have understood how and when it’s legal to use universal generalization and/or existential generalization. I have done with this exercise this way:
$\{∃xp(x), ∃xp(x) → \forall x∃y[p(x)→q(y)]\} ⊢ \forall xq(x) ∨ ∃xr(x)$

1. $\exists x\ p(x)$           Given
2. $\exists x\ p(x) \rightarrow \forall x\exists y[p(x)\rightarrow q(y)]$   Given
3. $p(a)$           EI 1
4. $p(a) \rightarrow [p(a) \rightarrow q(b)]$   EI & UI 2
5. $p(a) \rightarrow q(b)$       MP 3, 4
6. $q(b)$           MP 3, 5
7. $q(b) \vee  r(a)$       Add 6

so, I don’t understand why and how should follow  Ɐxq(x) ∨ ∃xr(x)

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I have an answer to this question ready, which I can only post if you are able to edit your question with an attempt(s), at solving it so far.

Comment: This reasoning is invalid. Consider $\{0,1\}$ and $p:\{0\}$, $q:\{0\}$ and $r:\{\}$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While at first I thought it was solvable, after looking at this problem for some time, I am convinced that it is a typo on behalf of the textbook. While it is possible to derive $\exists x q(x)$ from the premises, I do not think it possible to derive $\forall x q(x)$.

If the conclusion of the argument is false, so should be at least one of the premises. However, if you consider the case where q(1) is true, but q(2) is false, and $\forall x p(x)$ is true; then $\exists x p(x)$ is true, and $\exists y q(y)$ is true. This means that every premises is true, while the conclusion is false, and the argument is not valid.